# How to put a date from strftime in a nsstring in obj-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, nsstring, strftime

i want to be get a date (the current hour) from strftime and get it into a nsstring in obj-c for the iphone-os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/iphone-sdk-tip-function-for-getting-formatted-date-string-as-nsstring/

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `NSDate`'s `descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:`. More documentation about the call can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:). The API allows you to specify which component from a date you want output to an `NSString`, which is the return result of the API.

**Update:** If you really want to use `strftime` then take the `const char*`-typed result from that call and convert it to an `NSString*` by using `stringWithUTF8String`. More info on that [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithUTF8String:).

Comment: Can you detail a bit why you want to use `strftime` instead?

Comment: on the iphone os nsdate has a bug which i need to work around and i thought this would probably be the easiest
the bug is that it if you are on a regional format on your device which doesnt use 12hour format clock by default and the user has manually changed it to 12hour(via the switch) nsdate will give the time in 12hour with am/pm and such (the top one in the picture below). But if the device is set to a regional format such as US which 12hour is set automatically or the devices clock is on 24 (no matter what regional format) nsdate will give the time in 24 hour (the bottom 1 in the picture)